# Laravel 5 and MongoDB connection

Tags: mongodb, laravel, connection, jenssegers-mongodb

No suitable servers found (`serverselectiontryonce` set): [Failed connecting to '127.0.0.1:27107': Connection refused]

I install "jenssegers/mongodb": "^3.0" using composer, but am getting error, i can't connect mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I had mistaken the IP of my machine. I was in VM and used 127.0.0.1, when I needed to use 10.0.2.2, IP of my host machine. Wasted an hour for this. Maybe it saves someone's time...

Answer (score 0):

According to MongoDB [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/)

> mongod is the primary daemon process for the MongoDB system

According to above mentioned description ,it seems that **mongod** process is not running on your server and 27017 is default port for **mongod** instance

Please try executing following command to verify if mongod process is running on server

```
pgrep mongod
```

It will return process ID if **mongod** process is running on server otherwise nothing.

Issue following command in shell to start **mongod** process

```
mongod --noauth --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
```

Comment: I run this command "pgrep mongod" it returned the process ID but still it showing same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error.
I had to restart mongodb to make this work.

I used the command below

```
sudo service mongod restart
```